# Create a new list from two dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

This is a question about Python. I have the following list of dictionaries:

```
listA = [
          {"t": 1, "tid": 2, "gtm": 3, "c1": 4, "id": "111"},
          {"t": 3, "tid": 4, "gtm": 3, "c1": 4, "c2": 5, "id": "222"},
          {"t": 1, "tid": 2, "gtm": 3, "c1": 4, "c2": 5, "id": "333"},
          {"t": 5, "tid": 6, "gtm": 3, "c1": 4, "c2": 5, "id": "444"}
        ]
```

and a dictionary I wanted to compare with:

```
dictA = {"t": 1, "tid": 2, "gtm": 3}
```

I wanted to create a list of dicts that match all the items in **dictA** from **listA** and to include the "id" field as well:

```
listB = [
          {"t": 1, "tid": 2, "gtm": 3, "id": "111"},
          {"t": 1, "tid": 2, "gtm": 3, "id": "333"}
        ]
```

I tried doing this:

```
for k in listA:
    for key, value in k.viewitems() & dictA.viewitems():
        print key, value
```

But it's matching any item in **dictA**.

Comment: @sam, from question tags, and reading entire question , I guess it is Python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to check the *length* of the intersection, just checking `if dct.viewitems() & dictA.viewitems()` would evaluate to True for any intersection :

```
[dct for dct in listA if len(dct.viewitems() & dictA.viewitems()) == len(dictA)]
```

Or just check for a subset, if the items from dictA are a [subset](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects) of each dict:

```
[dct for dct in listA if dictA.viewitems() <= dct.viewitems()]
```

Or reverse the logic looking for a  [superset](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects):

```
 [dct for dct in listA if dct.viewitems() >= dictA.viewitems()]
```

Comment: how I love python one liners

Comment: I like your 2nd suggestion using subsets! Brilliant!

Comment: No worries,  it will also be a lot more efficient as it will short circuit and avoid creating  a set of the intersected objects.

Comment: What's the difference between **dict.viewitems()** and **dict.items()**? Why can't I use **dict.items()** in this case?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [dictionary view](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects):

```
listA = [
          {"t": 1, "tid": 2, "gtm": 3, "c1": 4, "id": "111"},
          {"t": 3, "tid": 4, "gtm": 3, "c1": 4, "c2": 5, "id": "222"},
          {"t": 1, "tid": 2, "gtm": 3, "c1": 4, "c2": 5, "id": "333"},
          {"t": 5, "tid": 6, "gtm": 3, "c1": 4, "c2": 5, "id": "444"}
        ]

dictA = {"t": 1, "tid": 2, "gtm": 3}

for k in listA:
    if dictA.viewitems() <= k.viewitems():
        print k
```

And for python 3 use:

```
if dictA.items() <= k.items():
    print(k)
```

Comment: Would be awesome if you leave a comment if voting down. Especially as this creates correct results.

Comment: Awesome! The line "if dictA.viewitems() <= k.viewitems()" translates to "if dictA is a subset of k" -- am I right?

Comment: Almost, it translates to "if dictA is subset or equal to k".

Comment: @Phidelux: In general, a set is considered to be a subset of itself.  If you want to refer to the case where the subset is not equal to the set, you usually refer to "proper subset".

Answer (score 1):

For python 2.7 :

```
listA = [
              {"t": 1, "tid": 2, "gtm": 3, "c1": 4, "id": "111"},
              {"t": 3, "tid": 4, "gtm": 3, "c1": 4, "c2": 5, "id": "222"},
              {"t": 1, "tid": 2, "gtm": 3, "c1": 4, "c2": 5, "id": "333"},
              {"t": 5, "tid": 6, "gtm": 3, "c1": 4, "c2": 5, "id": "444"}
            ]
dictA = {"t": 1, "tid": 2, "gtm": 3}
for k in listA:
    if all(x in k.viewitems() for x in dictA.viewitems()):
        print k
```

It gives output as :

```
{'tid': 2, 'c1': 4, 'id': '111', 't': 1, 'gtm': 3}
{'gtm': 3, 't': 1, 'tid': 2, 'c2': 5, 'c1': 4, 'id': '333'}
```

And if you want to create list then instead of `print`, add dictionary to list As follows:

```
listA = [
          {"t": 1, "tid": 2, "gtm": 3, "c1": 4, "id": "111"},
          {"t": 3, "tid": 4, "gtm": 3, "c1": 4, "c2": 5, "id": "222"},
          {"t": 1, "tid": 2, "gtm": 3, "c1": 4, "c2": 5, "id": "333"},
          {"t": 5, "tid": 6, "gtm": 3, "c1": 4, "c2": 5, "id": "444"}
        ]
dictA = {"t": 1, "tid": 2, "gtm": 3}
ans =[]
for k in listA:
    if all(x in k.viewitems() for x in dictA.viewitems()):
        ans.append(k)
        #print k
print ans
```

It gives output:

```
[{'tid': 2, 'c1': 4, 'id': '111', 't': 1, 'gtm': 3}, {'gtm': 3, 't': 1, 'tid': 2, 'c2': 5, 'c1': 4, 'id': '333'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,`all` will check the existence of `dictA` in `listA`.

```
[i for i in listA if all(j in i.items() for j in dictA.items())]
```

**Result**

```
[{'c1': 4, 'gtm': 3, 'id': '111', 't': 1, 'tid': 2},
 {'c1': 4, 'c2': 5, 'gtm': 3, 'id': '333', 't': 1, 'tid': 2}]
```