# Create a new list from two dictionaries (case insensitive)

Tags: python, dictionary

This is a question about Python. I have the following list of dictionaries:

```
listA = [
          {"t": 1, "tid": 2, "gtm": "Goofy", "c1": 4, "id": "111"},
          {"t": 3, "tid": 4, "gtm": "goofy", "c1": 4, "c2": 5, "id": "222"},
          {"t": 1, "tid": 2, "gtm": "GooFy", "c1": 4, "c2": 5, "id": "333"},
          {"t": 5, "tid": 6, "gtm": "GoOfY", "c1": 4, "c2": 5, "id": "444"},
          {"t": 1, "tid": 2, "gtm": "GOOFY", "c1": 4, "c2": 5, "id": "555"}
        ]
```

and a dictionary I wanted to compare with:

```
dictA = {"t": 1, "tid": 2, "gtm": "goofy"}
```

I wanted to create a list of dicts that match all the items in **dictA** from **listA** and to include the "id" field as well:

```
listB = [
          {"t": 1, "tid": 2, "gtm": "Goofy", "id": "111"},
          {"t": 1, "tid": 2, "gtm": "GooFy", "id": "333"},
          {"t": 1, "tid": 2, "gtm": "GOOFY", "id": "555"},
        ]
```

How do I compare the two dicts in a case-insensitive way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39245557/create-a-new-list-from-two-dictionaries

Comment: It is not same. He is asking about `case-insensitive` matching

Comment: @Ev.Kounis: case-insensitive this time.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: tobias_k It has to match "t", "tid", and "gtm" (case-insensitive). I forgot to ask this in the question I posted a couple of days ago.

@Chris_Rands I tried to copy the contents of **listA** to a new list and converting the case of the key and values to lowercase but I wanted to avoid creating a duplicate copy of the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to test each dictionary value manually:

```
def test(d1, d2):
    """Test if all values for d1 match case-insensitively in d2"""
    def equal(v1, v2):
        try:
            return v1.lower() == v2.lower()
        except AttributeError:
            # not an object that supports .lower()
            return v1 == v2
    try:
        return all(equal(d1[k], d2[k]) for k in d1)
    except KeyError:
        # d2 is missing a key, not a match
        return False

listB = [d for d in listA if test(dictA, d)]
```

This produces the 3 matches you are looking for:

```
>>> listA = [
...           {"t": 1, "tid": 2, "gtm": "Goofy", "c1": 4, "id": "111"},
...           {"t": 3, "tid": 4, "gtm": "goofy", "c1": 4, "c2": 5, "id": "222"},
...           {"t": 1, "tid": 2, "gtm": "GooFy", "c1": 4, "c2": 5, "id": "333"},
...           {"t": 5, "tid": 6, "gtm": "GoOfY", "c1": 4, "c2": 5, "id": "444"},
...           {"t": 1, "tid": 2, "gtm": "GOOFY", "c1": 4, "c2": 5, "id": "555"}
...         ]
>>> dictA = {"t": 1, "tid": 2, "gtm": "goofy"}
>>> [d for d in listA if test(dictA, d)]
[{'tid': 2, 'c1': 4, 'id': '111', 't': 1, 'gtm': 'Goofy'}, {'gtm': 'GooFy', 't': 1, 'tid': 2, 'c2': 5, 'c1': 4, 'id': '333'}, {'gtm': 'GOOFY', 't': 1, 'tid': 2, 'c2': 5, 'c1': 4, 'id': '555'}]
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(_)
[{'c1': 4, 'gtm': 'Goofy', 'id': '111', 't': 1, 'tid': 2},
 {'c1': 4, 'c2': 5, 'gtm': 'GooFy', 'id': '333', 't': 1, 'tid': 2},
 {'c1': 4, 'c2': 5, 'gtm': 'GOOFY', 'id': '555', 't': 1, 'tid': 2}]
```

but these include the extra keys. If you must have only certain keys, pick those keys in a new dictionary:

```
listB = [dict(dictA, id=d['id'], gtm=d['gtm']) for d in listA if test(dictA, d)]
```

This creates a copy of `dictA` and adds in the `id` and `gtm` keys from the matching dictionary:

```
>>> [dict(dictA, id=d['id'], gtm=d['gtm']) for d in listA if test(dictA, d)]
[{'tid': 2, 'id': '111', 't': 1, 'gtm': 'Goofy'}, {'tid': 2, 'id': '333', 't': 1, 'gtm': 'GooFy'}, {'tid': 2, 'id': '555', 't': 1, 'gtm': 'GOOFY'}]
>>> pprint(_)
[{'gtm': 'Goofy', 'id': '111', 't': 1, 'tid': 2},
 {'gtm': 'GooFy', 'id': '333', 't': 1, 'tid': 2},
 {'gtm': 'GOOFY', 'id': '555', 't': 1, 'tid': 2}]
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: I also like the way you can cherry-pick which key to include in the new list: `listB = [dict(dictA, id=d['id'], gtm=d['gtm']) for d in listA if test(dictA, d)]`

Comment: Alternatively, you could use a set of wanted `keys` and use something like `[{k: d[k] for k in d if k in keys}  for d in ...]`; this way, the keys like `gtm` don't have to be hardcoded.